# Seaborn catplot results in error by changing hue

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I have a dataset that looks like this:

|  | feature_1 | feature_2 | feature_3 | feature_4 | feature_5 | feature_6 | feature_7 | feature_8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -0.0020185900105266514 | -0.004525512052716703 | 0.004290147446159787 | 0.008121342033951665 | 0.019995812082180105 | 0.02034942055088337 | -0.02236798581774497 | -0.018665971326321824 |
| 1 | 0.008327938744324304 | 0.0057161731520134415 | 0.015149000101932132 | 0.014244686228342962 | 0.031266799783999905 | 0.02556201262830425 | 0.00491191281881069 | 0.002627771331087464 |
| 2 | 0.0056570911367399175 | 0.006780099460379361 | -0.0038521559525533412 | -0.0042372049750104175 | 0.025755417055772233 | 0.029050369619095566 | -0.0016924684746490136 | 0.001915807620861465 |
| 3 | -0.0066361424845156666 | -0.006829267976941566 | 0.008195242107994306 | 0.00993842145208005 | 0.02794638215808405 | 0.025168342480038512 | -0.013222987355723491 | -0.011178407242310215 |
| 4 | 0.005111817323414786 | 0.002367954071875622 | -0.0013140356150100757 | -0.0027816139194379794 | 0.025028881734832177 | 0.029704777330334546 | 0.0073461329985677545 | 0.008414726948742138 |

I have been able to create a [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) that is almost perfect, like this:

`sns.catplot(data=test_df, palette="dark", orient="h")`

Resulting in:

[image]

However, I want the colors to change depending on the results of a list (which I could append to `test_df`). The list is as follows:
`classifications = ["class_1", "class_2", "class_1", "class_1", "class_2"]`. Ideally, I'd like for the colors of the points to be different depending on the class.

Trying to add the `hue` parameter errors out, resulting in `ValueError: Cannot use 'hue' without 'x' and 'y'`

How can I change the colors of the points based on the values of the `classifications` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `class` column and [**`melt()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) into seaborn's preferred [long form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-data):

```py
test_df["class"] = classifications
melted = test_df.melt("class", value_name="value", var_name="feature")

sns.catplot(data=melted, x="value", y="feature", hue="class", palette="dark", orient="h")
```

[image: melted with hue]